# React scroll position after render when scrollTop is zero

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to understand react's behavior when data inside a scrollable div changes.

If the new data contains some of the currently visible items, react will manage the scroll position to keep those elements visible.

Imagine two sets of elements: `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i` and `f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m` and a container div that displays them in a vertical scrollable list, big enough to show only two elements at a time.

If I scroll down to element `f` and then change data, element `f` will still be the visible one. I believe that this works since every element has its own unique key.

The behavior is different if the scroll position is at 0: after the new elements are rendered, if I change back to the first set, the scroll will be still at zero and not on `f`. If you try this scrolling down by just one pixel works as expected.

Here a complete minimal working example: https://codepen.io/depsir/pen/OGGZPd

So the two questions:

1. is react doing this? and if so, is there any documentation about this behavior?
2. how can I make remain still the common visible elements among renders, even if `scrollTop = 0`?

---

Edit: I discovered that the behavior of the example is different among browsers: firefox mobile and safari keep the scroll position fixed in any case.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have pagination control. Also such control should provide some way of scrolling to position which was current on previous page, right?

Answering your question 1 about saving position for elements with the same key, you probably experiencing side effects of the list with indices used as keys (https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). So it works, but not what React recommends.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, probably the question was a bit confusing. I updated the question removing entirely the concept of pagination and infinite scroll, and I specified that I'm using unique keys different from the array index.

Comment: What do you mean by "common visible element" in question 2?

Comment: Could you explain your second question?

Comment: I mean, in the example link, when I change from second page to first page, having scrollTop = 0 and so element f visible in the second page, make element f (which is common to both pages) still be visible and possibly in the same position it was before the page change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this behavior is browser related, so now I'm able to respond to my first question:

> is react doing this? and if so, is there any documentation about this behavior?

NO, is the browser doing everything. You can try this simply with the DOM api:

```
// given a list of elements, in a scrollable container, 
// add a new element at first position
const list = document.getElementById("yourListId")  
list.insertBefore(getNewElement(), list.childNodes[0])
```

Here you can find a working example: https://codepen.io/depsir/pen/GaRwWa

As for question two, since react is doing nothing, it is clear that this behavior must be managed manually.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to pass `key` is unique value another than `index`, it may be same combination of `key` and any random value like `new Date() + index`. It's not recommended to use iterator as `key` prop by [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) you can also take a look [here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

you can try

```
{state.map((k) => { var d = new Date(); return(<Element key={d +k} id={k} />)})}
```

Or

```
{state.map((k) => { var random = Math.random(); return(<Element key={random +k} id={k} />)})}
```

this will try to keep the scroll position where you left.

Comment: I am NOT using index as key

Comment: Ohh got you but  i think as the key is going to same as the few array elements are same. Can try the other ways given

Comment: can you try your solution with the codepen I linked and, if it works, update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work at `scrollTop == 0`, then just make it always more :). It's hacky solution, but it works perfectly for me.

```
function InfiniteScroll(){
  /* ... */
  const ref = React.useRef()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handle = () => {
      if(ref.current.scrollTop === 0){
        ref.current.scrollTop = 1;
      }
    };
    handle();
    ref.current.addEventListener('scroll', handle)
    return () => {
      ref.current.removeEventListener('scroll', handle)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    /* ... */
      <div className='scroller' ref={ref}>
    /* ... */
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLdXKZ

You can even add a margin on top to get true pixel-perfect effect.

Comment: I tried something like that and in a true infinitescroll the behavior was faulty due to lot of subsequent scroll events. Anyway in other browsers, like safari, it does not work

Comment: What if initially there is less text so that the scroll is not there? elem.scrollTop = 1; would do nothing. How would you handle that?